# Program to launch a set of browser tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

I often have 5-6 browsers (google chrome) open with well over a hundred tabs sometimes.

I am looking for a way to bookmark a set of tabs and be able to launch that set of tabs into a window.

For example, lets say I have a browser windows with 8 tabs open, all related to mysql and another browser open with another 10 tabs related to another subject, or a window open with tabs related to my servers.

Is there some way I can book mark sets of tabs like that, so I can close these windows and then launch a set of related tabs anytime?

I know that you can set a set of tabs to open when you 1st launch google chrome, but I would need to have more then 1 set of tabs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Opera can do this (and so I suppose Google Chrome will eventually copy this feature too if it hasn't already) -- in Opera's bookmark folders, there's an extra item near the top of the list called "Open all folder items" which causes all bookmarks in the current folder to each get opened in separate tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you, but one thing I do is this.

Right click on the tab-bar and bookmark all the tabs.  When bookmarking I select a create a new bookmars folder on the `Bookmarks Bar`.

If you want to restore the tabs, from simply right click on the folder on the `Bookmarks Bar` and select `Open All Bookmarks`

Comment: awsome that is perfect, didnt realize you could launch a folder like that

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a Chrome extension called [TabCloud](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof).  From the description:

> TabCloud allows you to save any window session and restore it at a later date or on another computer. Effectively allowing you to sync open tabs between multiple computers.

I use it, but now I'm not sure why, because with Chrome Sync enabled you can bookmark all open tabs into a folder that will be synced to your other Chrome instances and open all bookmarks in the folder.